# Am I doing well this fixed point problem?

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

I would like to know if I'm doing well the following exercise. I think that I'm doing something wrong (specially in part (3)) but I don't know what...

Having $F(x)=x^2+\frac{3}{16}$ I have to answer the following quetions:

1. That function has got two fixed points. Which are those points?

   What I have done is:

   $x^2+\frac{3}{16}=x\space ; \space x^2-x+\frac{3}{16}=0 \space $ so $x_1 =\frac{3}{4}$ and $x_2=\frac{1}{4} \space $.$\space  $ So the two fixed points are $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$.
2. Being $\space  x_{k+1}=F(x_k)$ the iteration of the fixed point for that $F$, for which of the points obtained in part (1) is going to converge? (Let's suppose that the starting point is near of the fixed point).

   I have done the following:

   $F'(x)=2x \space \space;$ and $|F'(x)|$ has to be smaller that $1$ to converge. So $x=\frac{1}{4}$
3. For the fixed point/points obtained in part (2), how many iteration are needed more or less, so that the absolute accuracy is 10 times less.

   What I have done is:

   $|p_n-p|\le 10^{-1}|p-p_0|\le K^n|p-p_0|;\space 10^{-1}\le K^n; \space log_{10}10^{-1}\le log_{10}K^n; \space -1\le nlog_{10}K; \space \frac{-1}{log_{10}K}\le n; \space 3.321928\le n$ 
   where $K=F'(\frac{1}{4})=\frac{1}{2}\space$ 
   So we need 4 iterations at least.

Is this ok? Can anyone help me?

Comment: I would say that you are right on doing $F(x)=x$. Your are asked for fixed points of $F$, not the roots of $F$. Thus, you need $x$ such that $F(x)=x$, no such that $F(x)=0$.

Comment: Yes, that's it. But do you know what I'm doing wronog? @AugSB

Comment: Yes, your analysis now is correct.

Comment: ok; but I've got I doubt. I would do it as I have done but then, for make it sure, I have calculated the first 4 iterations, to see if the absolute accuracy is $10$ times smaller than it was at the beginning and it isn't... Is that possible? @YiannisGalidakis

Comment: I mean, for example if I start from the point $x_0=0.5$, at the beggining the absolute accuracy is $|0.5-\frac{1}{4}|=0.25$. Then, I have done the first $4$ iteration using $x_{k+1}=F(x_k)=x_k^2+\frac{3}{16}$ and I have obtained: $x_1=0.4375 ;\space x_2=\frac{97}{256}; \space x_3=0.3310699463; \space x_4=0.2971073093; \space $ so the absolute accuracy after the first $4$ iterations is $|0.2971073093-\frac{1}{4}|=0.0471...\space $ which is not $10$ times smaller than $0.25$ (the absolute accuracy at the beginning)... @YiannisGalidakis

Comment: @User160: Well, the question on this is a bit vague: It asks for *worse* accuracy while iterating. This is possible only if you iterate outside the interval $(-1/2,1/2)$, in which case $n=3$ is sufficient to throw the iteration off-orbit with the desired innacuracy, so the question doesn't apply for the convergent case. Try it with $x=1/2+0.1$ for example.

Comment: I don't understand really well what you say, you mean that it can work if I start from the point $x_0=1/2+0.1=0.6$ ? @YiannisGalidakis

Comment: No. What I mean is that $n=3$ does work if you start at $x_0=1/2+0.1$, so in this case you can expect a *worsening* of accuracy, while iterating. You can't have a worse accuracy when you iterate with $x_0\in(-1/2,1/2)$, because each iteration will have a *better* accuracy than the previous. So the question is really silly on the side of the proposer, and it applies only if the iteration diverges, in which case,  $n=3$ is sufficient. Remember the phrasing: Ten times *less* accuracy is equivalent to the accuracy *worsening* by at least one digit. This cannot happen when the iteration converges.